# Составить регулярное выражение для поиска палиндромов в строке. Python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Задание такое:

Выведите слова сообщения, являющиеся палиндромами, по убыванию их длин. Для повторяющихся слов в скобках указывать количество повторов.

Сделать нужно именно регулярным выражением (можно несколькими). Главная проблема с получением самих палиндромов.

Есть такая регулярка: `^(.)(.)(?:(.)(?:(.).?\4?)?\3?)?\2\1$`, но она находит палиндромы с длинной <=9, а нужно все.

Comment: А что ещё можно? А то вообще-то формально чистой регуляркой этого сделать нельзя.

Comment: Может, например, можно рекурсию и вырезать кусочки строк?

Comment: Ну вообще конкретных указаний нет (кроме использования регулярных выражений), так что думаю можно, но  только я не особо понимаю как это сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте это

```
/^((.)(?1)\2|.?)$/
```

Comment: Не работает. https://regex101.com/r/mLjVEN/1

Comment: Все работает https://regex101.com/r/RkryEX/1

Comment: Мне нужно конкретно на python.

Comment: Ок, но это нужно было уточнить в вопросе

Comment: хорошо, добавил в название) но вообще пайтон был указан в ключевых словах)

Comment: Ок, нашел на английском стэке только такое https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55486270/find-the-palindrome-of-a-string-by-using-python Как я понял на pyton регуляркой это сделать не получиться

Comment: Да, я видел это. Тем не менее задание дали такое. Может можно как-нибудь через несколько регулярок с применением методов из regex.